# Static class type variable in Java

Tags: java, object, static, pass-by-reference, nodes

Problem: To extract the leaves of a binary tree to a Doubly Linked List in Java.
Let the following be input binary tree

!        [1
     /     \
    2       3
   / \       \
  4   5       6
 / \         / \
7   8       9   10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL3xL.png)

Output:
Doubly Linked List
7<->8<->5<->9<->10

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node(int d)
    {
        data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;
    }
}

class extract_leaves_to_DLL
{
    static Node last=null;  //PLEASE SEE HERE

    static void extractL(Node root, Node last)
    {
        if(root==null)
            return;

        if(root.left==null && root.right==null)
        {
            if(last!=null)
            {
                root.right=last;
                last.left=root;
            }

            last=root; //LAST=ROOT ONLY WITHIN THIN FUNCTION
                 // IT BECOMES NULL AS SOON AS IT GETS OUT FROM THIS FUNCTION
            return;
        }
        if(root.left!=null)
        {
            extractL(root.left,last);
        }
        if(root.right!=null)
        {
            extractL(root.right,last);
        }
    }

    static void printReverseDLL(Node last)
    {
        if(last==null)
            return;
        while(last.left!=null)
            last=last.left;
        while(last.right!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(last.data+" -> ");
            last=last.right;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Node root=new Node(1);
        root.left=new Node(2);
        root.right=new Node(3);
        root.left.left=new Node(4);
        root.left.right=new Node(5);
        root.right.right=new Node(6);
        root.left.left.left=new Node(7);
        root.left.left.right=new Node(8);
        root.right.right.left=new Node(9);
        root.right.right.right=new Node(10);

        extractL(root,last);
        printReverseDLL(last);
    }
}
```

Here I have used a variable "last" of class Node type to keep track of the last leaf visited, so that it can be linked with the current node if it is a leaf. I declared last as "static Node last" hoping that like "static int" it also will not change the node it is pointing to after getting out of a function.

But, over here, despite declaring as static, "last" assumes the value it had in the parent function as soon as it gets out of the child function. So, last always remains null, and the previous leaf node is not tracked.

Consequently the list is empty. Please suggest how to make "last" behave like any static variable where the value of the variable can be changed from any function.

Comment: Little side note: Either stick to snake_case or camelCase, but don't mix them. The general Java standard would be camelCase.

Comment: Be careful with the second while loop in `printReverseDLL`: You don't change anything between iterations. That either means the loop is not necessary or it never terminates. If you use a good IDE, you get a warning when you do something like this. Netbeans e.g. shows a warning in the line `last=root;`: "addigned value is never used" and a warning "empty statement after while" in line `while(last.right!=null);`

Comment: @fabian:  Thanks for rectifying. That was a mistake while copying the code here and was not in the original code.. The code has been edited now.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `last` hides the static field. Use `extract_leaves_to_DLL.last` instead.

Comment: where should I declare "last" ?